# register_nav_menu is not working in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I've created my own menu page but it's not showing in WordPress website. I don't know how to `register_nav_menu` in `header.php`

I tried many things like

```
<?php register_nav_menu( 'navigation', __( 'top' ) ); ?>
```

added this code in `header.php` but still the same problem.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

use below code in header.php for fetch menu

```
<?php
            $header_menu_defaults = array(
                'theme_location'  => '',
                'menu'            => 'Top',
                'container'       => '',
                'container_class' => '',
                'container_id'    => '',
                'menu_class'      => 'nav',
                'menu_id'         => '',
                'echo'            => true,
                'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                'before'          => '',
                'after'           => '',
                'link_before'     => '',
                'link_after'      => '',
                'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                'depth'           => 0,
                'walker'         => ''
            );
            wp_nav_menu( $header_menu_defaults );
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php add this code

```
function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'Top' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_top' );
```

You can now go to Appearance » Menus page in your WordPress admin and try to create or edit a new menu. You will see ‘Top’ as theme location option.

Call your menu in the header

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'top', 
    'container_class' => 'top-class' ) ); 
?>
```

With the help of your menu top-class, you can use css [for more](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/)

Thanks